# Custom async Method

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, async-await

Is there a way to make an asynchronous call to a custom method in WP7 - WP8? 
In a Windows Forms app i would simply do this:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyMethod();
}

private async void MyMethod()
{
    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(5000));
}
```

However, it seems like the System.Threading.Tasks namespace is not supported in WP apps.

Then what should i do if i wished to act similarly in my WP7 - WP8 app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) for WP7.5 support. If you need WP7.0 support, your best bet is `BackgroundWorker`.

P.S. Your WinForms example would be better written as:

```
private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => MyMethod());
}

private void MyMethod()
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Following these best practices:

1. Avoid `async void`.
2. Don't use `Task.Run` in general-purpose library methods.

Comment: Thanks for that, but i still have an issue.

I wrote an asynchronous event handler for the TextBox.TextChanged event, but i get an error that states "invalid cross-thread call" when i try to do this:

await TaskEx.Run(() => MyMethod());

OR

await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyMethod());

How could i solve this?

Comment: Any UI updates need to be done on the UI thread, so they can't be within a call to `Task.Run`. You'll need to split up `MyMethod` into the "background" parts and the "UI" parts.